# Smart Contract ABI in Remix (Ethereum)

Tags: remix, dapps, ethereumjs, abi

When I deploy smart contract on the Rinkeby network using Remix the ABI of smart contract does not contain its address, so how do I connect it with my frontend application.

Comment: ABI is not supposed to have the address, you can see the transaction in the console, and with etherscan you can get the deployed address. Or you can see it in the deployed contracts section. Does that solve your problem?